# ViewPager refresh fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 4 tabs and #3 is a login screen. When I log in the inputfields on #2 and #4 will get information about the signed in user automatically. This never happens because the fragment is already created using `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);` Using notifyDataSetChanged() on the ViewPagerAdapter doesn't do anything.

> Tab 1: List of stuff
>
> Tab 2: Upload to list of stuff using information about user (name, email)
>
> Tab 3: Login or profile
>
> Tab 4: Support (requires e-mail address)

How do I update all fragments when I log in?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your ViewPagerAdapter.

```
public int getItemPosition( Object object ) {
     return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

It will make the notifyDataSetChanged() to work for your ViewPager.

Mark it as right if you found this useful.

Comment: It didn't do anything. :( I added `@Override` to that method but still didn't do anything.

Comment: it works but its laggy and @JonasB you need to set  the pageradapter.notifydatsetchanged on pageselecte

Answer (score 0):

Simply redoing the `setAdapter()` process:

```
Fragment[] items = { new Fragment1(), new Fragment2(), new Fragment3(), new Fragment4() };
mViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter( this, items );
mViewPager.setAdapter( mViewPagerAdapter );
```

**Edit:**
This was a dangerous approach. The app crashes sometimes because the adapter is looking for the container view to inflate the fragment in.